# Каким образом стоит понимать эту часть в задании по базам данных

Tags: sql

> "Регистрация товара осуществляется при каждом поступлении товара в
>   отдел продаж. При первом поступлении товара заносится вся необходимая
>   информация о нем, при повторном - только корректируется количество
>   товара на складе."

Если я правильно понял, изначально перечень с количеством товаров неизвестны - товары попадают в базу только при регистрации в отделе продаж? Как вообще происходит торговля в контексте этой задачи:

1. Товар сперва поступает в отдел продаж, там регистрируется информация о нем, включая количество, дальше этот товар отправляется на склад, с которого будет отправляться покупателю?

Или

2. Товар поступает со склада в отдел продаж и уже из него направляется
   покупателю?

[image: Условие задания полностью]

Comment: 1 вариант ваш более корректный

Comment: В жизни так же происходит - когда магазин закупает партию товаров, они сперва попадают в отдел продаж, а уже потом на склад?

Comment: На этот вопрос я вам не отвечу, потому что условие задачи и жизнь - это разные вещи. На бумаге все должно быть так, но как на самом деле все происходит - это другой вопрос.